Trying to find zenith and azimuth angles to satellite
I am working with satellite data. Each scene is approximately 30km squared with 1024 * 1000 pixels. I have the zenith and azimuth angle for each of the four corners, plus the center. I have latitude and longitude for each of the 1024000 pixels in the scene.
I wish to calculate zenith and azimuth angle for any pixel within the scene.
I use two algorithms to do so; Algorithm 1 calculates the satellites ECEF position and only needs to be performed once. Algorithm 2 then calculates the satellite angles for any pixel in the scene
Algorithm 1: Calculate Satellite Position

For each of the four corner pixels I use the latitude and longitude plus the angle information available for those four corners to find vectors from each corner to the satellite
def cornersToSatelliteVector(self, lonLats, satelliteZenith, satelliteAzimuth):
    assert lonLats.shape[1] == 2
    points = lonLats.shape[0]
    assert satelliteZenith.shape == (points,)
    assert satelliteAzimuth.shape == (points,)

    localVectorsToSatellite = np.zeros((points, 3, 1))
    localVectorsToSatellite[:, 0, 0] = np.sin(np.radians(satelliteZenith)) * np.cos(np.radians(satelliteAzimuth))
    localVectorsToSatellite[:, 1, 0] = np.sin(np.radians(satelliteZenith)) * np.sin(np.radians(satelliteAzimuth))
    localVectorsToSatellite[:, 2, 0] = np.cos(np.radians(satelliteZenith))

    return localVectorsToSatellite


Then I convert each of these four vectors to ECEF using the ENU to ECEF rotation matrix
def rotateEnuToEcef(self, enuVectors, enuLonLats ):

assert enuLonLats.shape[1] == 2
points = enuLonLats.shape[0]
assert enuVectors.shape == (points, 3, 1)

rotationMatrix = np.zeros((points, 3, 3))

# note; for each lonLat, lon occupies position 0, lat position 1
rotationMatrix[:, 0, 0] = - np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
rotationMatrix[:, 0, 1] = - np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) * np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
rotationMatrix[:, 0, 2] = np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) * np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
rotationMatrix[:, 1, 0] = np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
rotationMatrix[:, 1, 1] = - np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) * np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
rotationMatrix[:, 1, 2] = np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) * np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
rotationMatrix[:, 2, 0] = 0
rotationMatrix[:, 2, 1] = np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1]))
rotationMatrix[:, 2, 2] = np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1]))

rotatedVectors = np.zeros((points, 3))
for i in range(points):
    rotatedVectors[i, :] = np.dot(rotationMatrix[i, :, :], enuVector[i, :, :]).reshape((3,))

return rotatedVectors


Then I get the corner pixels locations in ECEF (altitude assumed to be zero for simplicity)
def latLonToEcef(self, lonLats, semi_major_axis = 6378137.0, eccentricity = 0.081819190842621, altitude = 0):
    assert lonLats.shape[1] == 2
    points = lonLats.shape[0]

    N = semi_major_axis / (1 - (eccentricity ** 2) * (np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) ** 2) ) ** 0.5
    x = (N + altitude) * np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) * np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
    y = (N + altitude) * np.cos(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1])) * np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 0]))
    z = ((1 - eccentricity ** 2) * N + altitude) * np.sin(np.radians(lonLats[:, 1]))

    out = np.zeros((points, 3))
    out[:, 0] = x
    out[:, 1] = y
    out[:, 2] = z

    return out


Finally I use least squares to find the point that is closest to where the vectors converge; i.e. the satellite position
def satellitePosition(self, cornersEcef, vectorsToSatellite):

    def __residuals(x, reference_points, unit_vectors):
        X_s, Y_s, Z_s = x
        res = []
        for (X_i, Y_i, Z_i), (u_xi, u_yi, u_zi) in zip(reference_points, unit_vectors):
            d_i = np.linalg.norm([X_s - X_i, Y_s - Y_i, Z_s - Z_i])
            res.append(X_s - (X_i + d_i * u_xi))
            res.append(Y_s - (Y_i + d_i * u_yi))
            res.append(Z_s - (Z_i + d_i * u_zi))

        return res

    assert cornersEcef.shape == (4, 3)
    assert vectorsToSatellite.shape == (4, 3)

    x0 = cornersEcef[0, :]
    result = least_squares(__residuals, x0, args=([cornersEcef, vectorsToSatellite]))
    return result.x



Now I have satellite position in ECEF, and I can use the latitude and longitude information to find ECEF for any of the pixels in the scene
I should be able to use this information to find zenith and azimuth angle from any pixel to the satellite as follows
Algorithm 2: Calculate Satellite Angles For Any Pixel

Get the vector from the pixel to the satellite as (satelliteECEF - pixelECEF)

Rotate the vector to the ENU frame for that pixel using the transpose of the rotation matrix used above

Convert the ENU vector to zenith and azimuth using
zenith = math.degrees(math.acos(vector[2]))
atan2 = math.degrees(math.atan2(vector[1], vector[0]))
azimuth = atan2 + (0 if atan2 >= 0 else 360)



As I do have zenith and azimuth for the center of the scene, I can test this and it works For example for pixel row=511, col=499, I calculate zenith = 7.077672 and azimuth = 100.882416 when the metadata tells me they should be 7.020788 and 100.615423 respectively. (it's not perfect but its a good start)
However, when I attempt to use steps 1 - 3 to verify the corner pixels I get very wrong answers. For example, for the upper left pixel I calculate zenith = 13.138654 and azimuth = 316.978049, when the angles I used as input for my algorithm are 8.333957 and 100.308818 respectively, suggesting the satellite is in a completely different part of the sky.
But as a result of Step 2 of Algorithm 1, I already do have ECEF vectors from the corners to the satellite. These ECEF vectors are very different to those calculated in Step 1 of Algorithm 2. If I plug these vectors into Step 2 of Algorithm 2 I get the correct angle.
So now I am confused. The Algorithm 2 produces correct satellite angles around the center of the scene, but very wrong angles the further from the center we get.
Is there anything obviously wrong with the steps I have outlined above, whether to calculate the satellite position, or the general steps to calculate zenith and azimuth for any pixel?

You need the triangulation of at least 3 satellites to compute position. So what exactly are you trying to do?

@pointdump I'm trying to find zenith + azimuth angles to a satellite from any scene pixel. The 1st two paragraphs explain this but I'll listen to criticisms on presentation. Paragraph 3 quickly describes 2 algorithms 1) find satellite position (using 4 known lat, lon, zenith, azimuth), 2) use satellite position to find zenith/azimuth to any pixel in the scene. Subsequent paragraphs explain the algorithms and show it is not producing correct results. My question is why is it not working. I need no additional information to do this, the problem is well-posed

admittedly I haven't mentioned altitude of a pixel in the problem description, but I could get it if I really needed it for my required level of accuracy
